# GoogleAPI with Google Sign In Account

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I've implemented google sign in with firebase auth in my application.
I'm trying to implement GmailAPI with signed in google account but was unable to find anything regarding both of them together.
I'm following 
https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis/blob/master/generated/googleapis/lib/gmail/v1.dart
and has implement this in the code

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.insert",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing",
    ]
);
```

Does the user needs authentication after this or the `uid` which is generated with this will be enough to authenticate user? 
Everywhere online with googleAPI examples, the user is authenticated online and I couldn't find anything with `google sign in`.

Comment: The Github link is not available for me, also there are zero public repos for them: https://github.com/dartlang

Comment: @csgabriella https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis/blob/master/generated/googleapis/lib/gmail/v1.dart

Comment: they updated the link yesterday

Comment: you will probably not authenticate with the `uid` persay, you will probably authenticate with a `token`. Having said that, I have setup oauth through firebase many times, and I've never run into anything super complicated, so if it is becoming super complicated, go back to the docs

Comment: @ewizard please check my question I asked after this. When a new user signs into the app with google, it asks permission for mailing settings which I've added in the scope. What does that mean now?

Comment: That just means the user is allowing you to see their email i  think. Not totally clear on what ur seeing ill be back in a sec. sounds like expected behaviour. The user has to authorize that

Comment: if you are still stuck, can you provide a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: @ewizard       https://imgur.com/1HJnGmS             https://imgur.com/sHn8mxz

Comment: Yah u should just be able to accept those somewhere, it is asking for permission to connect to various accounts that it needs

Comment: @ewizard I accept the permissions. But there's absolutely no documentation to work with dart yet. I'm stuck right now because I don't know what to do next. I have better explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61654745/what-is-the-correct-way-to-work-with-gmailapi.

Comment: k ill check it out

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on flutter but based on the examples found [here](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) The only things you need to autenticate to firebase programatically are the `token_id` and the `access_token` just like this:

```
final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );
```

Acording to that, to authenticate to firebase you just need to add the Sign in scopes: `'email', 'profile' and 'openid'` or the scopes: `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile' and 'openid'` (They usually represent the same depending on the library used). Then with the resulted access token you can use the firebase library to autenticate to firebase without re-authenticating.
Let me know if you need more information.

Edit:

You have to find the acces token received by Google sign in and pass the information fo firebase sign in. The access token should look something like this:

```
{
        "access_token": "ya29.a0Adw1xekVMTQRK0_EAdr1PfiOS97Lnz-VCLTJHw7...",
        "expires_in": 3599, 
        "refresh_token": "1//01iBd1CQsBUl2CgYIARAA...", 
        "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email openid", 
        "token_type": "Bearer", 
        "id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjE31ZmY0ZTEwOTkxZDZiMGA..."
}
```