# What is the correct way to work with GmailApi?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm able to get permission for user's emails with `GmailApi` from `googleapi` in flutter. However I'm finding it difficult to implement it. With `GmailApi` as a package I was sure that I won't have to fetch user information and mails from normal `http` so I researched a bit and followed some tutorials and threads on other `googleapis` and that had to do with the tags that are imported with package

```
import 'package:googleapis/gmail/v1.dart'
  show
  Label, Profile, GmailApi, Filter, Message, UsersResourceApi, Thread, BatchDeleteMessagesRequest, BatchDeleteMessagesRequest, Draft, UsersMessagesAttachmentsResourceApi; 
  //tags I mentioned in the paragraph above.
```

I was able to get user mail permission with this and initialised httpClient as logged in user.

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
      scopes: [
          GmailApi.MailGoogleComScope,
          GmailApi.GmailComposeScope,
          GmailApi.MailGoogleComScope,
          GmailApi.GmailInsertScope,
          GmailApi.GmailLabelsScope,
          GmailApi.GmailMetadataScope,
          GmailApi.GmailModifyScope,
          GmailApi.GmailReadonlyScope,
          GmailApi.GmailSendScope,
          GmailApi.GmailSettingsSharingScope,
      ]
);


final httpClient = googleSignIn.currentUser.authHeaders;



class GmailApi{
  static const MailGoogleComScope = "https://mail.google.com/";
  static const GmailComposeScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose";
  static const GmailInsertScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.insert";
  static const GmailLabelsScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels";
  static const GmailMetadataScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata";
  static const GmailModifyScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify";
  static const GmailReadonlyScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly";
  static const GmailSendScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send";
  static const GmailSettingsBasicScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic";
  static const GmailSettingsSharingScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing";


  final commons.ApiRequester _requester;

  UsersResourceApi get users => new UsersResourceApi(_requester);

  GmailApi(http.Client client,
      {core.String rootUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/",
        core.String servicePath = "gmail/v1/users/"})
      : _requester = new commons.ApiRequester(client, rootUrl, servicePath, USER_AGENT);
}
```

I couldn't find a way to work with above code so I tried this which I think is the correct way but there are no steps or documentation to follow to get it working unlike I found some threads and tutorials on `DriveApi` and `PeopleApi`.

this only shows value as null. What am I doing wrong?

```
import 'package:googleapis/gmail/v1.dart';

class ListClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListClassState createState() => _ListClassState();
}

class _ListClassState extends State<ListClass> {

  var leb = Profile();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(leb.emailAddress.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
;
```

Comment: what is happening? what is going wrong after the message where you accept permissions?

Comment: after the permissions screen you should be good to go, people should just be able to use your app

Comment: @ewizard thanks for helping with me this. There are no errors. With previous question I was confused if ```GmailApi``` needs additional permissions with but I am kind of sure now that the permissions are given to the user with this code. Right now I'm stuck because there's no documentation to follow for dart to work with GmailApi. I don't know how to read mails and stuff with code(dart). I hope you get it.

Comment: I suspect that where ever that code is, it is happening too quickly in your code flow. In other words, make sure that you are using async to sign the person in, and that the "signing in" actually completes before you try to display the email